# Codeigniter repopulating form data and get validation errors individually using redirect

Tags: forms, codeigniter, redirect

I am loading my form on index action of my Add controller and posting that form to submit_post action of the same controller. All I want is that if the post data doesn't fulfill the validation then it should redirect to the index action back rendering my form only and keeping the form fields filled with the values that were posted and also I would be able to get the each field error individually here are my controller actions

```
class Add extends CI_Controller {
    private $view = "";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->view = "add";
    }

    public function index()
    {
      $this->load->view("frontend/default", array("view" => $this->view));
    }

    public function submit_post()
    {
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
         {
              redirect('/add');
         }
         else
         {
             echo "Validated";
         }
    }
}
```

I have read many blogs and stackoverflow questions and found that this could be achieved via set_flashdata. Well, I did that and were able to print the all errors altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the line `redirect('/add');` With a redirect the validation class will be reloaded and all the information gathered during `form_validation->run()` is lost.

Here's my suggested code

```
     if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
     {
          $this->index();
     }
     else
     {
         echo "Validated";
     }
```

Comment: This approach works as far as validation is concerned but what actually happens is that when you hit the submit button the url in the url bar gets changed to **ci.local/add/submit_post** and never changed to **ci.local/add/** but validation works fine. I want to return back to **ci.local/add/** along with the validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should lоаd form_validation in your config file $autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation').
And then if you want to display the errors individualy, you should put this in your html right under every input field :

```
    <?php echo form_error('your fieldname');?>
```

Comment: And if you want to keep the fields populated : value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" . You do that for every field

Comment: I have already loaded the form_validation. Moreover form_error is working if I post the form on the same action which I am using for rendering it. In my case **index** is that action but I don't want to post the form on the same action which is being used to render the form.

Comment: Why do you want to redirect if the form validation is false? It doesn't send the form until is true so it keep looping over the form_validation until it is true .

Comment: Just take this line out redirect('/add'); and live it blank. it should work just fine

Comment: I think I am not making sense to you. ci.local/add/index this is the url that shows my form and that form gets redirected to ci.local/add/submit_post when I submit the form. Now I want to go back to ci.local/add/index location so that my gets rendered again with the error messages for each field. So for this purpose I am using redirect("/add").

Comment: I would do it this way : public function submit_post()
    {
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
         if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
         {
              
         }
         else
         {
             echo "Validated";
         } $this->load->view("frontend/default", array("view" => $this->view));

Comment: its working but not the way I want. This approach works as far as validation is concerned but what actually happens is that when you hit the submit button the url in the url bar gets changed to **ci.local/add/submit_post** and never changed to **ci.local/add/** but validation works fine. I want to return back to **ci.local/add** along with the errors.

Comment: That is the way it is suppose to work. When you hit the submit button it sends the form to the action atribute which is your your controller ci.local/add/submit_post. That's why it changes the url.

Comment: Ivo i know that but I want to return back to http://ci.local/add from http://ci.local/add/submit_post along with the errors. Kindly help me out, I hope that I have cleared my question now.

Comment: I think it is not possible to do that.Once you hit the submit button you are redirected to submit_post function which has own view set. And if the validation is false, you have already entered the if statement and you are showing the errors there. As long as you loop over the if statement you'll be showing the same view and the errors as well. If the validation is true you're entering the else statement where you can redirect to whatever page you want, but there won't be any errors to show anymore. So this is how it works.

Comment: You can't show errors with this  ci.local/add function, because there is no form validation in it and can't generate any errors, you see.Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Ok got it Ivo. So it means that I will have to stick to the same function while posting and rendering it. But If I want to implement this functionality what could be the best possible way?

Comment: Well, you can do the validation via javascript, jquery or manualy with php code like : if ($name == ""){echo "This field is required";} or something like this. You have to figure it out.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Ivo for your help.